# Is Iphone Source code usable in developing same android application?

Tags: android, ios

## Is Iphone Application Source code usable in developing same Android Application?

I am new in developing Android Application.I have already the source code of an iPhone application and I have to develop the same application in Android.

- I want to program the same User Interface as the one from the iPhone application in Android. Is it possible?
- Is it possible to use source code from the iPhone application while developing an Android application??
- How should I use that iphone application source code while developing the Android application?

Thank You in Advance..

Comment: I'm not sure that `You can use the source code` of iPhone , but You can use the `Logic` of that code for developing `Android` App

Comment: the answer is given please read, hope answer will help you!!

Comment: Yes i know that it is use two diffterent coding.Because someone told me that u can use of Iphone application source code thats why i am totally confused so i asked this question..thank you sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per yours question

**Is Iphone Application Source code usable in developing same Android Application??**

Iphone developers use OBJECTIVE C while Android developers uses JAVA. both are using different programming languages.

You asked

**I want make User Interface same as Iphone application in Android Application,so is it possible??**

The answer is yes you can make same possible ui, somewhere you may feel problem as you need to custom the components or it may also possible that you can not be able to custom in same way, but generally you can have same UI for both with respective programming approaches

**So is it possible to use source code of iphone application in developing android application??**

If we will see the re-usability of code than you can not reuse the code of iphone , you can use logic in same way.

**How should i use that iphone application source code in developing android application? Please anyone help medevelopment directly.**

The question is opinion based so i will say follow same screens modules and you can proceed, however you can not use yours code directly as java and objective c are different ones. you can use logic in the same way but not the code.